# Android TabHost inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-linearlayout

Hey... i'm trying to create an activity with the layout structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <TabHost android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
            <TabWidget android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
                /> 
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                >
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
     </TabHost>

     <some code here>

</LinearLayout>
```

What is wrong here? I'm getting nullPointerException in my activity

```
public class TabsActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabs);

        // Resources res = getResources();
        // TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
   }
}
```

The problem is with nesting. There is no problem with the TabHost as the main XML node. 
Thx!

Error:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Where are you getting a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: @CommonsWare: I see it in the log. It simply fails when trying to nest TabHost inside LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You are misinterpreting your stack trace.

The exception is occurring inside `Intent`. The `Intent` you are using to start the activity is invalid. Fix your `Intent`, and your problem will go away.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Hum... no idea what could be wrong with it. Other activities work but they do not have TabHost component in the layout. How should I call it? I call it like this startActivity(new Intent(this, TabsActivity.class));

Comment: @xpepermint: "I call it like this startActivity(new Intent(this, TabsActivity.class));" -- are you sure about that? That seems unlikely given your stack trace. You are creating your  `Intent` from an inner class of your activity, so `this` is unlikely to be a `Context`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Also if this TabsActivity is the startup activity, the problem is the same. Do you have a working code sample?

Comment: @CommonsWare: this is MyParentActivity.this btw.

Comment: @xpepermint: Here are a pair of projects demonstrating `startActivity()`: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Prefs/Dialogs/ http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/12-Activities/ Also note that you need to populate your tabs in `onCreate()`, otherwise you will get errors.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Hum... nope... my code is just like yours :). Do you have an example of TabHost inside LinearLayout layout? As I sad everything works but that special case.

Comment: @xpepermint: "Do you have an example of TabHost inside LinearLayout layout?" -- no. "As I sad everything works but that special case." -- as I said, that does not fit the stack trace you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the solution was to get the `TabHost` and call `setup()`. Hard to say if that's your problem here.

Comment: Ummm: findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost).setup(); Your screenshot doesn't show the whole trace, so it's hard to say if it's the same problem as mine.